# Why can't I make an optional paremeter default to member variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, self

I have a method `get_annotated_pkt_msg()` which takes a boolean parameter `show_timestamp`. I want this to be an optional parameter, and so that if the caller doesn't specify an argument it will default to what is set in the user-defined config. This config is stored in container `self.config` which has been passed-in by constructor dependency injection:

```
class XcpDaqFrame(XcpFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass init arguments to super-class.
        super(XcpDaqFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Passed by dependency injection to this constructor.
        self.config = config

    def get_annotated_pkt_msg(
            self,
            show_timestamp=self.config.getConfigItem('display.packet_time')):
        ##### SyntaxError here ^ (on the dot after 'self') ########
        """Return the annotated packet message

        :param bool show_timestamp:
        :rtype: str
        """
        # Optionally, show the timestamp of the packet.
        if show_timestamp:
            timestamp = get_timestamp()
            timestamp_msg = u", Timestamp: {} μs".format(timestamp)
        else:
            timestamp_msg = ""
        return timestamp_msg

frame = XcpDaqFrame(my_config)
frame.get_annotated_pkt_msg()
```

If I try the above it tells me, on the line marked above:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why is it that I can pass `self` to methods, but can't pass them `self.config`?

Comment: `self` is not defined. You should use `None` as the default then set it to what you want if it really is `None`.

Comment: @HuazuoGao It's weird that self *IS* defined in the first parameter, though. Thanks for the workaround, I just thought it would be more explicit to say specifically where the value is coming from in the method's header.

Comment: Default arguments is not evaluated at call, but at **definition**. `self` has no value at definition time, so it won't work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default parameters for a function are evaluated when the function is defined, not when the function gets called, so at the time of definition of the function (self has no value) , and you cannot use other parameters to the same function in default parameters. This also leads to other gotchas like *mutable default argument* (Read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)) .

Instead of that, you can try using some other default value (like `None` ) or so, and then default it to `self.config.getConfigItem('display.packet_time')` , if its `None` . Example -

```
def get_annotated_pkt_msg(
        self,
        show_timestamp=None):
    ##### SyntaxError here ^ (on the dot after 'self') ########
    """Return the annotated packet message

    :param bool show_timestamp:
    :rtype: str
    """
    if show_timestamp is None:
        show_timestamp = self.config.getConfigItem('display.packet_time')
    # Optionally, show the timestamp of the packet.
    ... #Rest of the logic
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and interesting link :)